# Remove all ratings from a SharePoint 2010 document library

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have a SharePoint 2010 document library in which I have enabled ratings. During testing, several people rated a number of documents, and now I'd like to reset all the documents back to zero. However, I cannot find a way to reset the ratings.

Things I've tried:

Disable ratings and re-enable: The ratings are still there.

Disable ratings, wait 24 hours, and re-enable ratings: The ratings are still there.

Using PowerShell and the SocialRatingManager, attempt to reset the rating (http://www.sharemuch.com/2011/03/22/resetting-sharepoint-2010-social-rating-using-powershell/): The script runs, but nothing changes.

Using the script above, modified to try to do a Delete() method on the rating result: "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation", even though I am running the SharePoint Powershell as Administrator, logged in as a site admin.

It seems like the last option should be the one to work, but I can't seem to get access to delete someone else's social ratings. Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Social tag manager errors/not workings are usually related to rights, here is a very good guide how to resolve the issues
http://www.sharepointpals.com/post/Programmatically-Manage-List-Items-Rating-with-Social-Rating-Manager-in-SharePoint-2013

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have run this as the app pool identity account, which is listed as administrator with full control on the User Profile Service. There's definitely something wrong with the DeleteRating Method because when I run it by passing the userProfile of the owner of the rating, it works (although it deletes all the ratings for that user, not just the one from this document library). Therefore, I know that the user account has permissions.